# How to get relevant data from a parent model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 database tables, Prospects and Profile. They're related by a One-to-one foreign key relationship

Model.py

```
class Prospect(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="profile_prospects")

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
```

In my view.py

```
prospects = prospects[:50]
```

I have a QuerySet of prospects (prospects is working correctly, exactly what I want), and I would like to retrieve a QuerySet of profiles based on the database model above. I tried

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(profile_prospects__in = prospects)
```

It returns an error of

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns
```

How can I get all the relevant profiles?

Comment: Are you sure it's a queryset? Or did you use values() at some point?

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(profile_prospects__in = prospects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I might be confused here. But isn't the *profile* automatically inherited by the *prospect* since it's a one-to-one relationship?

When you have the *prospect* you should be able to get the *profile* like this

> prospect.profile

Again, I might have gotten the question wrong.